# How can I replace the NAs of every coumn of a big dataset with the median of the non-missing entries of the column?

Tags: median, nas

I have a big dataset (1121 rows x 532 column).
Every column represent a single item of a self-report questionnaire.
I have several NAs (n= 3015).
I would like to replace every NAs with the median of every single column.

How can i do that?

I tried to clean the dataset from missing values with the `na.omit` function but R puts away the whole row where NAs was found.
This is a problem for me because after this operation I have  a dataset with only 641 rows. Every column represent the name of the scale and the item number (i.e. IUI23 ... IUI is the name of the scale and 23 the number of the item).

I need to find the median of each column whilst somehow not selecting the title of the column and then replace every NAs with the median of each column.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem and I would like to share my answer with you all.
I used the package "randomForest". 
I used the function in the package called na.roughfix (object, ... ) which is imputing all missing values by median/mode. It returns a completed data matrix or data frame. For numeric variables,NAs are replaced with column medians. For factor variables,NAs are replaced with the most frequent levels (breaking ties at random).If object contains no NAs, it is returned unaltered. 
My data name was IUI_data. I simply typed : 
IUI_data.roughfix<- na.roughfix(IUI_data). 
It worked perfectly!
For further informations on the package "randomForest" you can have a look here: cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf.